# R Shiny works in local, doesn't work in web

Tags: html, r, shiny

Locally, this code works, but I don't know why it doesn't work when deployed to shinyapps.io

https://albertjeey.shinyapps.io/r_script/

The input is smartphone's name (samsung, iphone, xiaomi, etc.) The slider is for number of tweets you want to crawl from twitter. Then you click 'analyze' wait a few seconds and the wordcloud, histogram, and all the tabs should display their stuff.

The UI:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(
pageWithSidebar(
headerPanel("Opinion Mining dengan Klasifikasi Naive Bayes"),

sidebarPanel(
  textInput("keyword", "Masukkan produk yang ingin dianalisis", ""),
  sliderInput ("tweetsize", "Jumlah tweets yang ingin dianalisis:",
              min=10, max=1000, value=100, step=10),
  actionButton("button1", "Analyze")
),

mainPanel(
  tabsetPanel(type="tab",
              tabPanel("WordCloud", plotOutput("wcplot")),
              tabPanel("Histogram", plotOutput("histplot")),
              tabPanel("Pie Chart", plotOutput("pieplot")),
              tabPanel("Data", tableOutput("dataplot")),
              tabPanel("Help",
                       HTML("<div><h4>Pada textfield yang tersedia di sisi kiri,
                            masukkan merk smartphone atau komputer yang
                            ingin diketahui sentimennya. Lalu, masukkan
                            jumlah tweet yang ingin dicari pada slider.
                            Setelah itu, tekan tombol 'analize' dan tunggu
                            hasil ditampilkan pada tab wordcloud, histogram, piechart,
                            dan data.</h4></div>")),
              tabPanel("About", textOutput("abouttext"))
  )
)
)
)
```

The server:

```
library(shiny)
library(twitteR)
library(RCurl)
library(tm)
library(wordcloud)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(e1071)
library(RTextTools)
library(dplyr)
library(caret)
library(data.table)

shinyServer(
  function(input, output)
  {
local_file = "stopwords_id.txt"
local_file2= "training_tweets.csv"
consumer_key <- 'the code'
consumer_secret <- 'the code'
access_token <- 'the code'
access_secret <- 'the code'
setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_secret)

#crawl_tweets <- reactive ({ searchTwitter(input$keyword, n=input$tweetsize, lang='id') })

observeEvent(input$button1, {

  keyword <- paste(input$keyword, "filter:replies") 

  crawl_tweets <- searchTwitter(keyword, n=input$tweetsize, lang='id')

  testing_tweets <- sapply(crawl_tweets, function(x) x$getText())

  #hapus emoji
  #testing_tweets <- iconv(testing_tweets, "latin1", "ASCII", sub = "")

  #hapus link
  #testing_tweets <- gsub("http(s?)([^ ]*)", " ", testing_tweets, ignore.case = T)

  #hapus html &amp
  #testing_tweets <- gsub("&amp", "and", testing_tweets)

  #write.csv(testing_tweets, file='D:/Hobby Projects/SKRIPSI/R Script/testing_tweets.csv')
  write.csv(testing_tweets, file='testing_tweets.csv')

  #preprocessing
  stopwords_id <- "stopwords_id.txt"
  cStopwords_id <- readLines(stopwords_id)

  #hapus2 yang gak kepake
  testing_corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(testing_tweets))
  testing_corpus_clean <- tm_map(testing_corpus, removePunctuation)
  testing_corpus_clean <- tm_map(testing_corpus_clean, content_transformer(tolower))
  testing_corpus_clean <- tm_map(testing_corpus_clean, tolower)
  testing_corpus_clean <- tm_map(testing_corpus_clean, removeNumbers)
  testing_corpus_clean <- tm_map(testing_corpus_clean, stripWhitespace)
  testing_corpus_clean <- tm_map(testing_corpus_clean, removeWords, c("cStopwords_id"))

  #naivebayes
  df_train <- read.csv("training_tweets.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  df_test <- read.csv("testing_tweets.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  df_train$class <- as.factor(df_train$class)

  train_corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(df_train$text))
  test_corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(df_test$x))

  train_corpus_clean <- tm_map(train_corpus, removePunctuation)
  train_corpus_clean <- tm_map(train_corpus_clean, content_transformer(tolower))
  train_corpus_clean <- tm_map(train_corpus_clean, tolower)
  train_corpus_clean <- tm_map(train_corpus_clean, removeNumbers)
  train_corpus_clean <- tm_map(train_corpus_clean, stripWhitespace)
  train_corpus_clean <- tm_map(train_corpus_clean, removeWords, c("cStopwords_id"))

  test_corpus_clean <- tm_map(test_corpus, removePunctuation)
  test_corpus_clean <- tm_map(test_corpus_clean, content_transformer(tolower))
  test_corpus_clean <- tm_map(test_corpus_clean, tolower)
  test_corpus_clean <- tm_map(test_corpus_clean, removeNumbers)
  test_corpus_clean <- tm_map(test_corpus_clean, stripWhitespace)
  test_corpus_clean <- tm_map(test_corpus_clean, removeWords, c("cStopwords_id"))

  train_dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(train_corpus_clean)
  test_dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(test_corpus_clean)

  convert_count <- function(x)
    {
    y <- ifelse(x > 0, 1,0)
    y <- factor(y, levels=c(0,1), labels=c("No", "Yes"))
    y
    }

  trainNB <- apply(train_dtm, 2, convert_count)
  testNB <- apply(test_dtm, 2, convert_count)

  classifier <- naiveBayes(trainNB, df_train$class, laplace = 1)

  pred <- predict(classifier, newdata=testNB)

  #write.csv(pred, file='D:/Hobby Projects/SKRIPSI/R Script/pred.csv')
  write.csv(pred, file='pred.csv')

  #wordcloud
  output$wcplot <- renderPlot({wordcloud(test_corpus_clean, random.order = F, max.words = 100, scale = c(4.5,1), colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))})

  #histogram
  #hist_df <- read.csv("D:/Hobby Projects/SKRIPSI/R Script/pred.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  judul = paste("Sentimen Produk", input$keyword)
  hist_df <- read.csv("pred.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  hist_df = hist_df[,c(2)]
  output$histplot <- renderPlot({ barplot(table(hist_df), main=judul) })

  #piechart
  pie_df = hist_df
  pie.freg <- table(pie_df)
  lbs = c("negatif", "netral", "positif")
  output$pieplot <- renderPlot({ pie(pie.freg, labes=lbs, main=judul) })

  #data
  df_pred <- read.csv("pred.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  df_data <- paste(df_pred$x, df_test$x)
  output$dataplot <- renderTable({ df_data })

})

}

)
```

These are the logs:

```
2017-12-16T01:45:47.174483+00:00 shinyapps[245848]:      1: local
2017-12-16T13:29:59.356929+00:00 shinyapps[245848]: Server version: 1.5.10-6
2017-12-16T13:29:59.356961+00:00 shinyapps[245848]: LANG: en_US.UTF-8
2017-12-16T13:29:59.356967+00:00 shinyapps[245848]: shiny version: 1.0.5
2017-12-16T13:29:59.356991+00:00 shinyapps[245848]: rmarkdown version: NA
2017-12-16T13:29:59.356963+00:00 shinyapps[245848]: R version: 3.4.3
2017-12-16T13:29:59.356993+00:00 shinyapps[245848]: knitr version: NA
2017-12-16T13:29:59.357018+00:00 shinyapps[245848]: jsonlite version: 1.5
2017-12-16T13:29:59.357028+00:00 shinyapps[245848]: htmltools version: 0.3.6
2017-12-16T13:29:59.357020+00:00 shinyapps[245848]: RJSONIO version: NA
2017-12-16T13:29:59.553198+00:00 shinyapps[245848]: Using jsonlite for JSON processing
2017-12-16T13:30:17.410322+00:00 shinyapps[245848]: Loading required package: bitops
2017-12-16T13:30:17.500332+00:00 shinyapps[245848]: Loading required package: NLP
2017-12-16T13:30:17.566585+00:00 shinyapps[245848]: Loading required package: RColorBrewer
2017-12-16T13:30:17.625006+00:00 shinyapps[245848]: Loading required package: SparseM
2017-12-16T13:30:17.694363+00:00 shinyapps[245848]: 
2017-12-16T13:30:17.694366+00:00 shinyapps[245848]: Attaching package: ‘SparseM’
2017-12-16T13:30:17.694367+00:00 shinyapps[245848]: 
2017-12-16T13:30:17.695143+00:00 shinyapps[245848]: The following object is masked from ‘package:base’:
2017-12-16T13:30:17.695146+00:00 shinyapps[245848]:     backsolve
2017-12-16T13:30:17.695145+00:00 shinyapps[245848]: 
2017-12-16T13:30:17.695146+00:00 shinyapps[245848]: 
2017-12-16T13:30:20.619535+00:00 shinyapps[245848]: Attaching package: ‘data.table’
2017-12-16T13:30:20.619536+00:00 shinyapps[245848]: 
2017-7-12-16T13:30:20.619535+00:00 shinyapps[245848]: Attaching package: ‘data.table’
2017-12-16T13:30:20.619536+00:00 shinyapps[245848]: 
2017-12-16T13:30:20.619532+00:00 shinyapps[245848]: 
2017-12-16T13:30:20.619975+00:00 shinyapps[245848]: The following objects are masked from ‘package:dplyr’:
2017-12-16T13:30:20.619976+00:00 shinyapps[245848]: 
2017-12-16T13:30:20.619977+00:00 shinyapps[245848]: 
2017-12-16T13:30:20.619977+00:00 shinyapps[245848]:     between, first, last
2017-12-16T13:30:20.655022+00:00 shinyapps[245848]: [1] "Using direct authentication"
2017-12-16T13:30:22.062111+00:00 shinyapps[245848]: Warning: Error in gsub: input string 20 is invalid UTF-8
2017-12-16T13:30:22.066757+00:00 shinyapps[245848]: Stack trace (innermost first):
2017-12-16T13:30:22.066759+00:00 shinyapps[245848]:     82: gsub
2017-12-16T13:30:22.066760+00:00 shinyapps[245848]:     80: FUN
2017-12-16T13:30:22.066760+00:00 shinyapps[245848]:     81: removeWords.character
2017-12-16T13:30:22.066761+00:00 shinyapps[245848]:     79: tm_map.SimpleCorpus
2017-12-16T13:30:22.066761+00:00 shinyapps[245848]:     78: tm_map
2017-12-16T13:30:22.066762+00:00 shinyapps[245848]:     77: observeEventHandler [/srv/connect/apps/r_script/server.R#74]
2017-12-16T13:30:22.066762+00:00 shinyapps[245848]:     13: runApp
2017-12-16T13:30:22.066763+00:00 shinyapps[245848]:     11: doTryCatch
2017-12-16T13:30:22.066763+00:00 shinyapps[245848]:     12: fn
2017-12-16T13:30:22.066764+00:00 shinyapps[245848]:     10: tryCatchOne
2017-12-16T13:30:22.066764+00:00 shinyapps[245848]:      9: tryCatchList
2017-12-16T13:30:22.066765+00:00 shinyapps[245848]:      8: tryCatch
2017-12-16T13:30:22.066765+00:00 shinyapps[245848]:      7: connect$retry
2017-12-16T13:30:22.066766+00:00 shinyapps[245848]:      6: eval
2017-12-16T13:30:22.066766+00:00 shinyapps[245848]:      5: eval
2017-12-16T13:30:22.066767+00:00 shinyapps[245848]:      4: eval
2017-12-16T13:30:22.066767+00:00 shinyapps[245848]:      3: eval
2017-12-16T13:30:22.066768+00:00 shinyapps[245848]:      2: eval.parent
2017-12-16T13:30:22.066768+00:00 shinyapps[245848]:      1: local12-16T13:30:20.619532+00:00 shinyapps[245848]: 
2017-12-16T13:30:20.619975+00:00 shinyapps[245848]: The following objects are masked from ‘package:dplyr’:
2017-12-16T13:30:20.619976+00:00 shinyapps[245848]: 
2017-12-16T13:30:22.062111+00:00 shinyapps[245848]: Warning: Error in gsub: input string 20 is invalid UTF-8
2017-12-16T13:30:22.066757+00:00 shinyapps[245848]: Stack trace (innermost first):
2017-12-16T13:30:22.066759+00:00 shinyapps[245848]:     82: gsub
2017-12-16T13:30:22.066760+00:00 shinyapps[245848]:     80: FUN
2017-12-16T13:30:22.066760+00:00 shinyapps[245848]:     81: removeWords.character
2017-12-16T13:30:22.066761+00:00 shinyapps[245848]:     79: tm_map.SimpleCorpus
2017-12-16T13:30:22.066761+00:00 shinyapps[245848]:     78: tm_map
2017-12-16T13:30:22.066762+00:00 shinyapps[245848]:     77: observeEventHandler [/srv/connect/apps/r_script/server.R#74]
2017-12-16T13:30:22.066762+00:00 shinyapps[245848]:     13: runApp
2017-12-16T13:30:22.066763+00:00 shinyapps[245848]:     11: doTryCatch
2017-12-16T13:30:22.066763+00:00 shinyapps[245848]:     12: fn
2017-12-16T13:30:22.066764+00:00 shinyapps[245848]:     10: tryCatchOne
2017-12-16T13:30:22.066764+00:00 shinyapps[245848]:      9: tryCatchList
2017-12-16T13:30:22.066765+00:00 shinyapps[245848]:      8: tryCatch
2017-12-16T13:30:22.066765+00:00 shinyapps[245848]:      7: connect$retry
2017-12-16T13:30:22.066766+00:00 shinyapps[245848]:      6: eval
2017-12-16T13:30:22.066766+00:00 shinyapps[245848]:      5: eval
2017-12-16T13:30:22.066767+00:00 shinyapps[245848]:      4: eval
2017-12-16T13:30:22.066767+00:00 shinyapps[245848]:      3: eval
2017-12-16T13:30:22.066768+00:00 shinyapps[245848]:      2: eval.parent
2017-12-16T13:30:22.066768+00:00 shinyapps[245848]:      1: local
```

Comment: Tell us more about why this doesn't work. What do you mean by "work"? 
Are there error messages? The app in the link starts up successfully, but other than that, we have no idea how to use your app.

Comment: okay. So the input is smartphone's name (samsung, iphone, xiaomi, etc.) The slider is for number of tweets you want to crawl fro twitter. Then you click 'analyze' wait a few seconds and the wordcloud, histogram, and all the tabs should display their stuff.

Comment: What do the logs say when the app crashes?

Comment: I already added the logs in my question

Comment: Try converting your csv files to UTF-8. You can do this easy with notepad++ for example

Comment: The txt - file as well of course

Comment: @BertilBaron  sorry for the super late reply and, thanks, it worked. And also thank you for not being the rude commenters, which I've just experienced in my recent question